# PHP version is wrong in phpinfo() output

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I run my web application in nginx server with php-fpm version on debian wheezy, inside a docker container.

I update my php version to 5.6.1.

```
RUN echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
RUN apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php5-fpm php5-mysqlnd php5-cli supervisor
```

If I do the following commands inside my container, version is ok and seems correctly updated:

```
php -v // 5.6.6
/usr/sbin/php5-fpm -v // 5.6.6
```

But if I go to my document root and do phpinfo(), the php version is wrong in Core -> PHP version (5.4.36, the default one with debian:wheezy). More nginx version output is wrong too.

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you try restarting your server after updating the PHP version?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command.

If **apache**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If **nginx**

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

After you install any server modules, it is a good habit that you restart your apache,nginx.

Comment: Yes, but i'm in a docker container and I start my nginx server every time my container is running. So I don't need to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

All right, it was a "docker-compose" misunderstanding.
I needed to do a `docker-compose up -d` to rebuild, recreate and restart my services.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue running Laravel with Homestead using NGinx. What is the non-Dock equivelant?